# Grep - get text between all occurences of tag

Tags: grep

I'm close to getting what I need from this:

```
grep -o '<div class="item">.*</div>' file.html > result.html
```

Except that this is giving the first instance (including the tags themselves but I only want the text within the tags, and all the text and tags after it until the close of the last div. So given:

```
<body><div class="item">text</div><h3>Hello</h3><div class="item">text2</div></body>
```

I'm trying to get:

```
text
text2
```

But I'm getting

```
<div class="item">text</div><h3>Hello</h3><div class="item">text2</div>
```

How to correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, I recommend a specialized tool to parse `HTML` or `XML`, You can use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) `grep -P`

```
grep -oP '(?<=<div class="item">)[^<]*' file.html
```

you get,

```
text
text2
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the -P flag? That's GNU grep, correct?

Comment: correct, `GNU-grep` for use `positive lookbehind` ..... without `-P option`, with double pass, think up

Comment: `grep -o '<div class="item">[^<]*' file.html | grep -o '[^>]*$'`

Comment: Thanks, that does it!